# DropdownButtonFormField Rendering issue

Tags: flutter

I am doing a project in flutter web and I created a widget of *DropdownButtonFormField*. I am trying to do is that I select values from the dropdown and save them into the database and the next time when a user opens that page I fetched the saved values from the database and assigned them to these dropdowns for update purposes, Now the issue is that DropDownWidget is working perfectly fine in debugging mode, but when I deploy the project at firebase hosting and reopen the page it didn't display the values that are coming from the firestore. In Debugging it is working fine and fetched values are displayed.

here is the code of the dropdown widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppDropDownWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppDropDownWidget({
    Key? key,
    this.value,
    required this.onChanged,
    required this.hintText,
    required this.items,
    required this.title,
    this.icon,
    this.isValidate = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final T? value;
  final void Function(T?) onChanged;
  final String hintText;
  final String title;
  final List<DropdownMenuItem<T>> items;
  final Widget? icon;
  final bool isValidate;

  @override
  State<AppDropDownWidget> createState() => _AppDropDownWidgetState<T>();
}

class _AppDropDownWidgetState<T> extends State<AppDropDownWidget<T>> {
  T? _value;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _value = widget.value;
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant AppDropDownWidget<T> oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    _value = widget.value;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12),
      child: DropdownButtonFormField<T>(
        isDense: true,
        icon: widget.icon,
        hint: Text(
          widget.hintText,
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xFF95A1AC),
          ),
        ),
        style: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: 14,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
        ),
        validator: widget.isValidate
            ? (T? value) {
                if (value == null) {
                  return "This field is required";
                } else if (value is String && (value).isEmpty) {
                  return "This field is required";
                } else {
                  return null;
                }
              }
            : null,
        value: _value,
        items: widget.items,
        onChanged: (value) {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());

          _value = value;
          setState(() {});
          widget.onChanged(_value);
        },
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          isDense: true,
          labelText: widget.title,
          labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF95A1AC)),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFDBE2E7), width: 1),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          ),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFDBE2E7), width: 1),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          ),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFDBE2E7), width: 1),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          ),
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the code of the page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:its_stocks_admin/src/base/modals/error_dialog.dart';
import 'package:its_stocks_admin/src/components/home/update_stock/update_success_dialog.dart';
import 'package:its_stocks_admin/src/data/data.dart';
import 'package:its_stocks_admin/src/services/reporting_schedule_firestore_service.dart';
import 'package:its_stocks_admin/src/widgets/app_button_widget.dart';
import 'package:its_stocks_admin/src/widgets/app_dropdown_widget.dart';
import 'package:its_stocks_admin/src/widgets/decorated_container_widget.dart';
import 'package:its_stocks_admin/src/widgets/heading_text_widget.dart';
import 'package:its_stocks_admin/src/widgets/loading_widget.dart';
import 'package:its_stocks_admin/src/widgets/no_data_widget.dart';
import 'package:reusables/mixins/form_state_mixin.dart';
import 'package:reusables/reusables.dart';

class ReportingScheduleView extends StatefulWidget {
  const ReportingScheduleView({
    Key? key,
    required this.successCallback,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final void Function(int) successCallback;

  @override
  State<ReportingScheduleView> createState() => _ReportingScheduleViewState();
}

class _ReportingScheduleViewState extends State<ReportingScheduleView>
    with FormStateMixin {
  var _isLoading = true;
  var _hasError = false;

  ReportingScheduleModel? _reportingSchedule;
  final _scheduleService = ReportingScheduleFirestoreService();
  final _monthDays = List.generate(31, (i) => i + 1);

  Future<void> _initState() async {
    try {
      _hasError = false;
      _reportingSchedule = await _scheduleService.fetchOneFirestore('1');
      _isLoading = false;
    } catch (_) {
      _isLoading = false;
      _hasError = true;
    }
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget child;
    if (_isLoading) {
      child = const LoadingWidget();
    } else if (_hasError) {
      child = const NoDataWidget(message: 'Something went wrong');
    } else {
      child = LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (_, c) => Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
          child: DecoratedContainerWidget(
            constraints: c,
            child: Form(
              key: formKey,
              autovalidateMode: autovalidateMode,
              child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                  child: HeadingTextWidget(text: 'Manage Reporting Schedule'),
                ),
                AppDropDownWidget<ScheduleTime>(
                  onChanged: (_) {
                    _reportingSchedule?.schedule = _ ?? ScheduleTime.daily;
                    _reportingSchedule?.day = 1;
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  hintText: 'Select Schedule',
                  value: _reportingSchedule?.schedule,
                  items: ScheduleTime.values
                      .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: e,
                            child: Text(e.value),
                          ))
                      .toList(),
                  title: '',
                ),
                if (_reportingSchedule?.schedule == ScheduleTime.weekly) ...[
                  AppDropDownWidget<String>(
                    value: days[(_reportingSchedule?.day ?? 0)],
                    isValidate:
                        _reportingSchedule?.schedule == ScheduleTime.weekly,
                    onChanged: (_) {
                      _reportingSchedule?.day = days.entries
                          .firstWhere((element) => element.value == _)
                          .key;
                    },
                    hintText: 'Select Weekday',
                    items: days.values
                        .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: e,
                              child: Text(e),
                            ))
                        .toList(),
                    title: '',
                  ),
                ] else if (_reportingSchedule?.schedule ==
                    ScheduleTime.monthly) ...[
                  AppDropDownWidget<int>(
                    value: _reportingSchedule?.day,
                    isValidate:
                        _reportingSchedule?.schedule == ScheduleTime.monthly,
                    onChanged: (_) {
                      _reportingSchedule?.day = _ ?? 0;
                    },
                    hintText: 'Select Day of the Month',
                    items: _monthDays
                        .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: e,
                              child: Text(e.toString()),
                            ))
                        .toList(),
                    title: '',
                  ),
                ],
                AppButtonWidget(
                  onTap: submitter,
                  title: _reportingSchedule == null ? 'Save' : 'Update',
                ),
              ]),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return child;
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onSubmit() async {
    try {
      await Awaiter.process(
        future: _scheduleService.updateFirestore(
          _reportingSchedule!,
        ),
        context: context,
        arguments: _reportingSchedule == null ? 'Saving...' : 'Updating...',
      );
      if (!mounted) return;
      const UpdateSuccessDialog(
        message: 'Reporting Schedule Updated Successfully!',
      ).show(context);
      widget.successCallback(0);
    } catch (_) {
      ErrorDialog(error: _.toString()).show(context);
    }
  }
}

enum ScheduleTime {
  @JsonValue(0)
  daily('Daily'),
  @JsonValue(1)
  weekly('Weekly'),
  @JsonValue(2)
  monthly('Monthly');

  final String value;

  const ScheduleTime(this.value);
}

final days = {
  1: 'Monday',
  2: 'Tuesday',
  3: 'Wednesday',
  4: 'Thursday',
  5: 'Friday',
  6: 'Saturday',
  7: 'Sunday',
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem here.
Works on debug, does not work in production.
But I noticed that if you first render the component with `value: null`, and after that fill in the selected value in a `setState()`, it works.

Answer (score -1):

There is a bug in this code because the opening bracket of the return statement is missing. Without it, the code will not compile.

```
import ‘package:flutter/material.dart’;

class AppDropDownWidget extends StatefulWidget {
const AppDropDownWidget({
Key? key,
this.value,
required this.onChanged,
required this.hintText,
required this.items,
required this.title,
this.icon,
this.isValidate = false,
}) : super(key: key);

final T? value;
final void Function(T?) onChanged;
final String hintText;
final String title;
final List<DropdownMenuItem> items;
final Widget? icon;
final bool isValidate;

@override
State createState() => _AppDropDownWidgetState();
}

class _AppDropDownWidgetState extends State<AppDropDownWidget> {
T? _value;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_value = widget.value;
}

@override
void didUpdateWidget(covariant AppDropDownWidget oldWidget) {
super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
_value = widget.value;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
child: Column(
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
children: [
Text(
widget.title,
style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
),
SizedBox(height: 8),
DropdownButton(
value: _value,
icon: widget.icon,
hint: Text(widget.hintText),
onChanged: (T? newValue) {
setState(() {
_value = newValue;
});
widget.onChanged(newValue);
},
items: widget.items,
),
if (widget.isValidate && _value == null)
Text(
‘This field is required’,
style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 12),
),
],
),
);
}
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I was asking about DropdownButtonFormField, not about DropdownButton